# What's the difference between "Dialekt" and "Mundart"?

Tags: dialect, word-choice, difference, synonym

Are "Dialekt" and "Mundart" exact synonyms, or is one more official, more colloquiel etc? Or are there regional differences in their use? Or maybe one is a broader term than the other and might cover more speech varieties than the other?

So what's the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Man kann die Begriffe "Dialekt" und "Mundart" gewöhnlich austauschen. [Auf Wikipedia gibt es eine Sicht der Dinge](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialekt#Dialekt_und_Mundart), die hier einen Unterschied treffen will. Die Unterscheidung betrifft die schriftliche Aufzeichnung/Schreibweise:

> Die spezifischen Eigenheiten eines Dialektes können schriftlich aufgezeichnet werden, ein typisches Beispiel ist hier das bairische: „I håb no nia koan Rausch ned k'håbt!“ Unkundige können solche Aufzeichnungen je nach Kenntnis der Hochsprache korrekt ablesen und zumeist ihren Sinn beim Lesen verstehen. Im Gegensatz hierzu ist Mundart die Art Wörter auszusprechen, und zwar unabhängig von ihrer Schreibweise. Die Mundart eines Sprechers kann sich somit auch beim Vorlesen eines in akkurater Hochsprache verfassten Textes zeigen.
>
> Als typisch wäre hier die niederdeutsche Mundart (nicht die Sprache) zu nennen, bei der das „s“ in den Kombinationen „sp“ und „st“ nicht als „sch“, sondern als „s“ ausgesprochen wird. Dies lässt sich im Schriftbild – unter Missachtung der Rechtschreibregel – durch das deutsche Sonderzeichen ß andeuten: „Die Außßprache von Herrn Schmidt ist für süddeutsche Dialektßprecher schwer verßtändlich.“
>
> Aufschluss über die Zugehörigkeit eines Sprachraumes ergibt das Schibboleth. Ein Schibboleth vereinigt verschiedene Aspekte der lokalen Mundart so, dass das Wort für einen Außenstehenden nicht korrekt auszusprechen ist.

Dieser Unterschied zwischen *Dialekt* und *Mundart* wird allerdings nicht durchgängig gemacht. In Wörterbüchern und Fachwörterbüchern der Linguistik findet man in der Regel eine Definition, bei der Dialekt und Mundart gleichgesetzt werden.

Answer (score 8):

Ich ergänze Splattne, wenn ich Heinrich Löffler zitiere, der in seiner Einführung in die Dialektologie (eines der Standardwerke im Unterricht an der Universität, jedenfalls in der Schweiz) schreibt: "So stellt sich die einfache Frage nach der Definition des Begriffes *Mundart* und *Dialekt* gleich zu Beginn als eines der Probleme, wenn nicht gar als eines der Hauptprobleme der Dialektforschung heraus." (S. 1) Er verweist später auf die Vielfalt der Kriterien, die eine klare Unterscheidung erschweren, und spricht von einer achtlosen Vermischung derselben (S. 8). Er zeigt zwar einige Unterscheidungskriterien auf, verwendet die Begriffe aber schliesslich synonym.

Gerade im alltagssprachlichen Kontext spricht daher nichts gegen eine synonyme Verwendung der beiden Begriffe.

Quelle: Löffler, Heinrich: Dialektologie. Eine Einführung. Tübingen: Gunter Narr 2003.

Answer (score 4):

In Switzerland the term "Mundart" is normally used as synonym to Swiss-german, not as one for dialect.

Comment: You're saying "Mundart" is used to refer specifically to Swiss German and not generally for arbitrary dialects?

Comment: Most of the time yes.
For example a song written in Mundart is a song written in swiss-german, it doesn't matter which dialect of swiss-german it is.

Answer (score 3):

`Dialekts` are spoken by the people in a region. It can be very hard to understand for people from other parts of the country.

`Mundart` is used in theater or TV. It is intended to be understood by everyone. It tries to carry some feeling for the `Dialect`.

Answer (score 3):

There are indeed regional differences in the usage, see here:

http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_1/f20/

Comment: Thanks, learned something. Being from the Rhineland, it is obvious for me that "Mundart=Dialekt". Of course, what is implied in South Germany by "Mundart", here is "Platt".

Answer (score 3):

Nach meiner subjektiven Einschätzung hat es einen kleinen Bedeutungsunterschied: Mundart ist eher positiv bewertet, Dialekt eher negativ.
Exterm ausgedrückt: Dialekt spricht der, der 'kein richtiges Deutsch kann'. Mundart spricht der Heimatverbundene Einheimische.

Ein Indiz für diese Einschätzung: Es gibt Mundart-Theater (positiv), aber kein Dialekt-Theater. Siehe dazu aber auch [bernd_ks Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1341/974)